# Better way to shuffle two related lists

Tags: python, list, shuffle

Is there better ways to randomly shuffle two related lists without breaking their correspondence in the other list? I've found related questions in `numpy.array` and `c#` but not exactly the same one.

As a first try, a simple `zip` trick will do:

```
import random
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]]
b = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
c = zip(a, b)
random.shuffle(c)
a = [e[0] for e in c]
b = [e[1] for e in c]
print a
print b
```

It will get the output:

```
[[1, 2], [7, 8], [3, 4], [5, 6], [9, 10]]
[2, 8, 4, 6, 10]
```

Just find it a bit awkward. And it also need an additional list as well.

Comment: you can use `zip` to unzip the lists as well:  `a,b = zip(*c)`

Comment: I would also generally not recommend a program design where you need to keep a set of parallel lists.  Just keep 1 list.  Create some sort of class or something to unify your data.

Comment: If one want to do such work by `numpy`, here is a good solution:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601373/better-way-to-shuffle-two-numpy-arrays-in-unison

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Given the relationship demonstrated in the question, I'm going to assume the lists are the same length and that `list1[i]` corresponds to `list2[i]` for any index `i`. With that assumption in place, shuffling the lists is as simple as shuffling the indices:

```
 from random import shuffle
 # Given list1 and list2

 list1_shuf = []
 list2_shuf = []
 index_shuf = list(range(len(list1)))
 shuffle(index_shuf)
 for i in index_shuf:
     list1_shuf.append(list1[i])
     list2_shuf.append(list2[i])
```

Comment: As a fan of list comprehensions: list1_shuf = [list1[i] for i in index_shuf]

Comment: @kojiro : doesn't matter : n*append_ops + n*append_ops = n*(append_ops+append_ops) = 2*n*append_ops

Answer (score 34):

If you are willing to install a few more packages:

Req:
NumPy (>= 1.6.1),
SciPy (>= 0.9).

pip install -U scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
list_1, list_2 = shuffle(list_1, list_2, random_state = 0)
```

Answer (score 6):

If you have to do this often, you could consider adding one level of indirection by shuffling a list of indexes.

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:13:38) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import random
>>> a = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]]
>>> b = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
>>> indexes = range(len(a))
>>> indexes
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> random.shuffle(indexes)
>>> indexes
[4, 1, 2, 0, 3]
>>> for index in indexes:
...     print a[index], b[index]
...
[9, 10] 10
[3, 4] 4
[5, 6] 6
[1, 2] 2
[7, 8] 8
```

Answer (score 4):

So far, all solutions created new lists in order to solve the problem. If the lists *a* and *b* are very long you may want to shuffle them in place. For that you would need a function like:

```
import random

def shuffle(a,b):
    assert len(a) == len(b)
    start_state = random.getstate()
    random.shuffle(a)
    random.setstate(start_state)
    random.shuffle(b)

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b = [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]
shuffle(a,b)
print(a) # [9, 7, 3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 8, 6]
print(b) # [19, 17, 13, 11, 12, 15, 14, 18, 16]
```

Comment: My best answer for large list without numpy!

Answer (score 2):

A fast answer using numpy please refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4602224/2792278):
You can use

```
p = numpy.random.permutation(len(a))
```

To create a new list of indexes for both lists and use it to reorder them.

In your scenario:

```
In [61]: a = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]]
In [62]: b = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
In [63]: import numpy as np
In [64]: a_ar, b_ar = np.array(a), np.array(b)
In [65]: p = np.random.permutation(len(a))
In [66]: a, b = a_ar[p].tolist(), b_ar[p].tolist()
In [68]: a
Out[68]: [[3, 4], [7, 8], [5, 6], [1, 2], [9, 10]]
In [69]: b
Out[69]: [4, 8, 6, 2, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do an unzip at the end to limit the awkwardness a bit?

```
import numpy as np
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [4,5,7]
list_zipped = list(zip(list1,list2))
np.random.shuffle(list_zipped)
list1,list2 = zip(*z) #unzipping
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I'm missing something here, but it looks like you're just shuffling 1 of the lists and the other one is re-arranged to match the order of the first list. So what you have is the best way to do this without making it more complicated. If you want to go the complicated route you can just shuffle 1 list and use the unshuffled list to do a lookup in the shuffled list and rearrange it in that way. In the end you end up with the same result you started with. Why is creating a third list a problem? If you really want to recycle the lists then you can simply replace list b with what you're using for list c and then separate it later on back to a and b.

Answer (score -1):

Modified version of [AlexConfused's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49883307/843953) which is more general and be copied and used directly:

```
from random import shuffle, getstate, setstate


def shuffle_inplace(lst, state):
    """ shuffle multiple lists in-place using order determined by state """
    setstate(state)
    shuffle(lst)


lst1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
lst2 = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

s = getstate()
shuffle_inplace(lst1, s)
shuffle_inplace(lst2, s)

print(lst1)
print(lst2)
```

Comment: You probably want to include a link to their answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49883307/843953 Also, your version isn't more general IMO, it just moves the capture of the RNG state outside the function. Sure, you can now shuffle any number of lists using this RNG state, but it misses the entire point of the question which is to shuffle lists simultaneously. To generalize their approach you could have your function take _any number of lists_ instead of only two lists.

Comment: I tried to edit the poster's answer before, but the edit queue was too long, hence I posted an answer myself. I added a direct link to the original answer as well now. The question was how "to randomly shuffle two related lists without breaking their correspondence in the other list" without, e.g., zipping, shuffling and extracting lists again. There was no mention of doing so simultaneously. Maybe you're confusing this question with a related one? I needed this precisely because I had to randomly shuffle N lists without breaking correspondence in a succinct and convenient fashion.